# Topological description of an octagon with identifications.

Tags: general-topology

It is well know that a torus with two holes is the resulting of some identifications of an octagon, as explained in picture 34 here: http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/mathematics-and-statistics/mathematics/surfaces/content-section-2.3.7. But, if we have an octagon with the identifications $abcda^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}$, is it also a torus with two holes?

Answer (score 1):

The way you tell is by triangulating your octagon, then

1. Seeing that the resulting object is a manifold (by looking at what happens at vertices).
2. Checking that it is orientable
3. Computing the Euler characteristic (triangulate the octagon, and see how many edges and vertices there are after gluing).

If the answers are yes, yes, $-2$ then it must be a surface of genus $2.$

Comment: But how can I prove it rigorously?

Comment: The very way I am describing.

Comment: Because I have to describe generators of the fundametantal group of the $2$-torus (in the standard presentation), in terms of $a,b,c,d$... How can I do it knowing that $\pi_1(T)=aba^{-1}b^{-1}cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$

Comment: The point is that you can know it is a surface of genus two without explicit presentation (just by Euler characteristic).

Comment: But I need the it!